# Limit to number of client-side validators on one aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got 5 required field validators on an aspx page.
With all validators active, none of the code behind any of the command buttons on the page will fire.
However, with ANY four out of five validators active, buttons all function ok.

Is there a limit to the amount of validators that can be used on a single page? Is there any other reason that this could be happening?

Help appreciated, thanks..

Daf.

Markup looks like this..

```
> <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Admin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RegisterUser.aspx.cs" Inherits="LectureQuestions.Interface.Admin.RegisterUser" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageTitle" runat="server">Register New User
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleTxt" runat="server">Register New User
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <table ID="tblInputField" runat="server" width="100%" cellspacing="15">
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"></td>
                <td width="20%">First Name</td>
                <td width="60%">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Width="98%"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtFirstNameRequired" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"></td>
                <td width="20%">Last Name</td>
                <td width="60%">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Width="98%"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtLastNameRequired" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtLastName" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"></td>
                <td width="20%">E-mail</td>
                <td width="60%">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="98%"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtEmailRequired" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"></td>
                <td width="20%">Phone</td>
                <td width="60%">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" Width="98%"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtPhoneRequired" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"></td>
                <td width="20%">Password</td>
                <td width="60%">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Width="98%"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"></td>
                <td width="20%">User Type</td>
                <td width="60%">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="txtUserType" runat="server" Width="99.5%">
                        <asp:ListItem>-- Please Select --</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Student</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Lecturer</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Admin</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <asp:Label id="txtUserTypeValidation" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"></td>
                <td width="20%">Course</td>
                <td width="60%">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="txtCourse" runat="server" Width="99.5%">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td width="10%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table ID="tblAllValidationMsg" runat="server" width="100%" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"></td>
                <td width="80%" align="center">
                    <asp:Label id="allValidationMsg" runat="server" height="22px" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td width="10%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table ID="tblCommandButtons" runat="server" width="100%" cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td width="25%"></td>
                <td width="25%" align="right">
                    <asp:Button class="navbutton" ID="btnRegister" runat="server" 
                        Text="Register User" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
                </td>
                <td width="25%" align="left">
                    <asp:Button class="navbutton" ID="btnCancel" runat="server" 
                        Text="Cancel" onclick="btnCancel_Click" />
                </td>
                <td width="25x%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: No. There is no limit. And what do you mean by "Active"?

Comment: Code will help find the solution

Comment: Which one did you remove when it started working again?

Comment: @codingbiz.. Hello again :)

Comment: @codingbiz.. By "Active", i mean I've commented out validators one at a time..

Comment: according to my what i m getting from your question is you want to fire the button's click if any of four fields are filled or some thing like this, if you want to such type of thing then you cannot do it with C#, you must need to go with javascript or jquery validations..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I placed a second regular expression validator on one of the fields for testing.
When I removed this validator, problem ceased. Don't know how or why; any advice on this welcome..

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**
No there is no limit to validations on the page.

**Misc:**
Pranay has provided the fix in his answer.